# Why wouldn't Perl CGI script run

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, perl, cgi

I'm using Apache on CentOS and am trying to run a Perl CGI script as directory index so it will run automatically as a subdomain.  I added `DirectoryIndex script.cgi` and added a `Directory` stanza noting the path `/var/www/folder` enabling the script to run.

The only way the script would run is if I also add a `File *.cgi` stanza within the directory stanza (or even outside of it) and move the relevant section to it:

```
    Options +ExecCGI and SetHandler perl-script
```

I'm still learning Apache, and wondering why just referencing the folder wasn't enough.  Why do I also have to add a File stanza and reference `*.cgi`?  The CGI script would have been the only file in the folder.

Comment: Can you please post more of the actual stanzas you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to execute a cgi-script, apache2 needn't to know about perl. So I'd remove the `SetHandler` directive.

To debug it, look at your `/var/log/apache2/error.log` or similar. Your directory has to be accessible by apache. The script you like to execute need to have the execution flag set.

Example config:

```
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin/">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
```